# convert raster image to polygons using python

Tags: python, computer-vision, gdal, qgis, vector-graphics

i have a raster image (single channel), from which i want make set of polygons and store them in geoson. Whats the fastest and most efficient way!

Comment: No complete solution, but I would suggest having a look at OpenCV's [`findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gae4156f04053c44f886e387cff0ef6e08). More complete usage example (including Douglas Peucker approximation): https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: [gdal_polygonize.py - Produces a polygon feature layer from a raster.](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html)